# Do I file 1040 when amending if 1040 has not changed?

Tags: united-states, form-8606, amended-tax-return

If I am amending my tax return by only updating form 8606 for which there is no change to any numbers on form 1040, do I need to include my 1040 over again?  I know I need to include the 1040x, but it seems pointless to include the 1040 if nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall, you send the 1040X, and only the forms that changed, no need to send entire return or even 1040.